# Getting yoyo effect on window resize with slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, slidetoggle

Hope you're all well I was wondering if any of you guys could help me. I'm trying to add a window resize effect to turn off and on slideToggle. The purpose is to hide a filter navigation on mobile and have it as a dropdown.

I have written the following code but every time I resize the screen I get an up down up down effect. Like a yoyo. I have tried several methods but nothing is working.

```
init () {
const $window = $(window)
const $width = $(window).width()
const $refine = $('.filter span')
const $filters = $('.collection-filters-container')
const $sort = $('.collection__filter')

function resize () {
  if ($width > 991) {
    $filters.show()
    $sort.show()
  } else {
    $refine.on('click', (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation()
      $filters.slideToggle()
      $sort.slideToggle()
    })
  }
}

  $window.resize(resize).trigger('resize')

}
```

Thank you for taking the time to read my post. I look forward to your reply.

Kind regards,

Comment: why are you triggering resize event after binding it? `$window.resize(resize).trigger('resize')`

Comment: Hi @Bhumika107 thanks for replying. I normally use the `resize(resize).trigger('resize')` as I find it allows me to scale the browser like I would media queries, and the JS will respond. Whereas if I just use `resize(resize)` I have found in the past I still have to click the refresh button.

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle?